# Pass table name a parameter to the Data Context method using LINQ to SQL in C#

Tags: c#-4.0, linq-to-sql

I have created a method which delete data from the database by joining a db column with a csv file, I have a list of tables in a Data Context which I need to iterate, i means that I need to change the table name by passing it as parameter to the method.

Basically I need to use this method for all the table present in the Data Context

Current hard coded Table name in a GetTable method: dw_Job
DataContext Object: job

Here is my code

```
            var query = from line in File.ReadAllLines(file, Encoding.GetEncoding(1252))
                        //let jobrecord = line.Split(',')
                        join j in job.GetTable<dw_Job>() on
                        Convert.ToInt32(line.Split(',').GetValue(factColPos))
                        equals j.JobID
                        select j;

            foreach (var deletejob in query)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(deletejob);
                job.dw_Jobs.DeleteOnSubmit(deletejob);
            }

            job.SubmitChanges();
```

I can able to provide if you need any further details of my code. Please correct me on this

Thanks in advance